# Реализация поиска с помощью searchController'a

Tags: ios, swift

Привет! Несколько дней никак не могу сделать поиск по таблице. Есть порядка 27 секций (A-Z, 0-9, А-Я), в каждой секции, соответственно, в алфавитном порядке ячейки.

Выглядит все примерно так:

[image]

Массив секций выглядит вот так:

```
let titlesForSections: [String?] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "K", "L",
                                "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
                                "Y", "0 - 9", "А - Я"]
```

Массив ячеек имеет формат

```
let cellsForSections = [["AA", "AB", "AC"], ["BA"], ["CA", "CB"]]
```

Ну и так далее. 
Не понимаю как сделать функцию для сортировки этого двумерного массива по тексту из searchController.searchBar. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    var sortedArray = ???
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что нужно обновлять все массивы

```
let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
var sortedCells: [[String]]  = []   
for array in cellsForSection {
    sortedCell.append(array.filter({(cellString) -> Bool 
        return cellString.contatins(searchText)    
    })
}
```